# How to escape/quote elements of Scala collection to pass to AngularJS initialization?

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework

I need to initialize a collection of String constants for an angularjs autocomplete directive. Maybe there is another way but I do so injecting the values to the relevant Ctrl. To this end I define these values in my `index.scala.html` like so. Note that CcyPair is a Scala Enumeration type:

```
<script>
    angular.module("backTestDemoApp").value("ccyPairs",
        [
            @CcyPair.values.map("'%s'".format(_)).mkString(",")
        ]
    );
</script>
```

I'd like to get this as HTML output:

```
<script>
    angular.module("backTestDemoApp").value("ccyPairs",
        [
            'CHFEUR', 'CHFGBP', 'CHFJPY', ...
        ]
    );
</script>
```

but instead what I get in the HTML is this:

```
<script>
    angular.module("backTestDemoApp").value("ccyPairs",
        [
            &amp;quot;CHFEUR&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;CHFGBP&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;CHFJPY&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;CHFUSD&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;EURCHF&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;EURGBP&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;EURJPY&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;EURUSD&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;GBPCHF&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;GBPEUR&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;GBPJPY&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;GBPUSD&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;JPYCHF&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;JPYEUR&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;JPYGBP&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;JPYUSD&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;USDCHF&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;USDEUR&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;USDGBP&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;USDJPY&amp;quot;
        ]
    );
</script>
```

I have also tried wrapping each element in the single or double quotes HTML codes but still get garbage back by the Play template:

```
@CcyPair.values.map("&#39;%s&#39;".format(_)).mkString(",")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found the solution in the [Play Template documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates#escaping). The solution is to wrap the code in the `@Html(_)` to prevent Twirl from auto-escaping and instead use the raw output as is. Therefore, the complete solution is:

```
<script>
    angular.module("backTestDemoApp").value("ccyPairs",
        [
            @Html(CcyPair.values.map("'%s'".format(_)).mkString(","))
        ]
    );
</script>
```